# Getting a Segmentation fault: 11 with Swift 5.2 when using FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath

Tags: swift, xcode

I've got a custom Swift script that is similar to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --sdk macosx swift

import Foundation

let path = FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath
```

On Swift 5.1 and lower it runs just fine, but upon updating to Swift 5.2, I get

```
0. Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret test.swift -enable-objc-interop -stack-check -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name test 
1. Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
2. While running user code "test.swift"
0 swift 0x000000010dd2f4ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1 swift 0x000000010dd2ecc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6710f42d _sigtramp + 29
3 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffee6222018 _sigtramp + 2131831816
4 swift 0x0000000109ab29ba llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::GenericValue>) + 458
5 swift 0x0000000109ab9a2b llvm::ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain(llvm::Function*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, char const* const*) + 2011
6 swift 0x0000000109a8eaea performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, bool, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, bool, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 14362
7 swift 0x0000000109a834a5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 55813
8 swift 0x00000001099f94d3 main + 1283
9 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff66f167fd start + 1
10 libdyld.dylib 0x000000000000000b start + 2567870479
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Have there been any breaking changes that I'm not aware of?

Comment: there seems to be a bug in the swift header. The documentation says the property can be `nil`, but it is not optional.

Comment: Got the same crash with my script nothing related to `FileManager` in there. I think it crashes during compilation.

Comment: Right. Seem like a compiler bug. I've filed an issue at the Swift bug tracking system. Haven't been able to find a workaround yet.

Comment: For reference: [SR-12403](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that in this case, the problem was in rogue overlay dylibs that were in place because I've been using SwiftGen.

The solution is to either uninstall SwiftGen by calling

```
brew uninstall swiftgen
```

or following [Nikolaj's answer](http://%20https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12403?focusedCommentId=55302&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-55302) from Swift bug tracking system by reinstalling SwiftGen with

```
--build-from-source
```

option and removing the dylibs from "lib" folder.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thanks Michal! How did you find out what was causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Having older Xcode versions installed in parallel, I simply switched the Xcode version and avoided dealing with SwiftGen.
You can change the Xcode version in the menu under

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools