# Segmentation fault on a simple swift script

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault

I have a very simple script written in swift and running this with `swift file.swift`

```swift
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")
```

and this gives me a segfault error with this message

```
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret file.swift -enable-objc-interop -stack-check -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name file 
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
2.  While running user code "file.swift"
0  swift                    0x00000001101354ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000110134cc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6c0aa5fd _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffee3e196a8 _sigtramp + 2010575048
4  swift                    0x000000010beb89ba llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::GenericValue>) + 458
5  swift                    0x000000010bebfa2b llvm::ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain(llvm::Function*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, char const* const*) + 2011
6  swift                    0x000000010be94aea performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, bool, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, bool, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 14362
7  swift                    0x000000010be894a5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 55813
8  swift                    0x000000010bdff4d3 main + 1283
9  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6beb1cc9 start + 1
zsh: segmentation fault  swift file.swift
```

any ideas as to where the problem is? Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried putting the code to Xcode and it works as it should.

Comment: I don't know anything about swift, but it's probably, because `"www.google.com"` ist not a full URL. Try `"https://www.google.com"`

Comment: The code is right. I have tested it in Xcode

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881990/670119) worked in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a script which was working and suddenly stopped. Exactly on the line where I have created an URL. It was working on Xcode but not from terminal.

Looks like, it is bug.

If you first compile by using `swiftc` then run it, it is working.

I have found the answer in the following page:

https://blog.kulman.sk/workaround-for-swift-scripts-crash/

Comment: Thank you for this link! I was about to tear my hair out :D I had the same use case as you.